# Using Aggregate Function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Why this query is not working:-**

```
SELECT b.byhub, 
       Count(awbno) 
FROM   (SELECT awbno, 
               byhub, 
               entrydatetime, 
               Max(entrydatetime) 
        FROM   wbbooking 
        GROUP  BY awbno, 
                  byhub, 
                  entrydatetime) B 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT refno, 
                          Max(entrydatetime) 
                   FROM   wbmmreceiving 
                   GROUP  BY refno) R 
               ON B.awbno = R.refno 
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, b.entrydatetime) BETWEEN '2016-10-13' AND '2016-10-13' 
GROUP  BY b.byhub
```

**After Execute this query I have obtain this type of Error:-**

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
No column name was specified for column 4 of 'b'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'r'.
```

Comment: What's the SQL engine that you are using? Is it case sensitive? B vs b?

Comment: Since you grouped by `entrydatetime`, what are you expecting `Max(entrydatetime)` to yield?

Comment: Your query seems more complicated than needed for this purpose.

Comment: Please show wbbooking and wbmmreceiving tables descriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors occur, because you have not specified a name for the aggregate column `Max(entrydatetime)`. Change it to `Max(entrydatetime) AS max_entrydatetime`.

This query is a bit strange. The subquery `B` selects `entrydatetime` as well as `Max(entrydatetime)`. But since `entrydatetime` is included in the group by list, `Max(entrydatetime)` will always be the same as `entrydattetime`.

If you want the last `entrydatetime` per `awbno` and `byhub`, then don't group by `entrydatetime` and only include it as `Max(entrydatetime)` in the select list. If you really want to group by this date column, then don't include it as `Max(entrydatetime)`.

What is the purpose of the second subquery? None of its returned columns are used except for joining. Is it needed for the count?

Why include a where-clause in the outer query? If you include it in the first subquery, it is more efficient and the `entrydatetime` column needs not to be returned any more.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify column names for your subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT b.byhub, 
       Count(awbno) 
FROM   (SELECT awbno, 
               byhub, 
               entrydatetime, 
               Max(entrydatetime) max_entrydatetime
        FROM   wbbooking 
        GROUP  BY awbno, 
                  byhub, 
                  entrydatetime) B 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT refno, 
                          Max(entrydatetime) max_entrydatetime
                   FROM   wbmmreceiving 
                   GROUP  BY refno) R 
               ON B.awbno = R.refno 
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, b.entrydatetime) BETWEEN '2016-10-13' AND '2016-10-13' 
GROUP  BY b.byhub
```